# Check for multiple Interpolation values in Angular Reactive

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a way to check for more then true or false for an interpolated.
In my case i have a form which i want to update the bttn based one the state of the form.

```
<button  (click)="saveEmail()"  [disabled]="emailEditForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{ mode }} </button>
```

the above is my current code and mode can be either , Save, Update, Duplicate but i would like the text to be more User friendly like. Create New Email, Update Email, Duplicate current Email.
Is this posible or is this another case of having to use *ngIf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways actually..

> ```
> 1. Inline if:
> ```

```
 <button  (click)="saveEmail()"  [disabled]="emailEditForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{ mode=="Save"? "Create New Email":mode=="Update"? "Update Email": "Duplicate current Email" }} </button>
```

> 2 Cleaner way:

//TS

```
export class MyComponent {
    public Modes = { Save: "New Email", Update: "Update Email", Duplicate : "Duplicate current Email"  };
}
```

//HTML

```
<button  (click)="saveEmail()"  [disabled]="emailEditForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{ Modes[mode] }} </button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The cleaner way is the way to go as it avoids endless chaining of values